# How to return nodes related to a set of nodes but not to eachother

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to display a network in the neo4j browser.

I have a graph where the nodes are `Person` and there are two types of relationships `MANAGED` and `FRIENDS`.

Given a initial person with id `'123'` I can find all of the people recursively managed by them, like so

```
MATCH (p:Person { person_id:"123" })-[r:MANAGES *0..100]->(managed:Person)
RETURN managed,r
```

What I want to do now is to display all of these people and all of the managed arrows but in addition, display all of the people that have `FRIENDS` relationship with the `managed` people and the `friends` arrows. However I do not want to show the `FRIENDS` arrow between people in `managed` to other people in `managed` even if a `FRIENDS` relationship exists.

Some non functional pseudocode might be

```
MATCH (p:Person { person_id:"123" })-[m:MANAGES *0..100]->(managed:Person)-[f:FRIENDS]-(friend:Person)
RETURN managed,m, f if friend not in managed, friend if friend not in managed
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use COLLECT to condense your results into lists so that you can run a FILTER on them. ([functions](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/))

```
MATCH (p:Person { person_id:"123" })-[m:MANAGES *0..100]->(managed:Person)-[f:FRIENDS]-(friend:Person)
// m is already a list because *..100, so need to unpack it to consolidate repeated values
UNWIND m as ms 
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT p) as p, COLLECT(DISTINCT ms) as m, COLLECT(DISTINCT managed) as managed, COLLECT(DISTINCT f) as f, COLLECT(DISTINCT friend) as friend
RETURN managed, m, FILTER(r in f WHERE NOT r in m) as f, FILTER(n in friend WHERE NOT n in managed) as friend
```

You can use UNWIND with some filters to get the rows back, but that will take some extra work and make the return data larger (because, for example, p will be returned row number of times).